# Delete *.ZIP files older than 15 days

Tags: bash, find, sh

I'm currently using a PHP script to back up my databases daily and it works like a charm.  After the backup, I am using the shell script below to zip the backup file:

```
find /home/root/BACKUPS/backup.sql | xargs zip -czvPf /home/root/BACKUPS/$(date +%F)_backup.sql.zip
```

I need to add a piece of code that will also scan previously created `"$(date +%F)_backup.sql.zip"` and delete any that are older than 15 days.

Does anyone have any recommendations on how to make this work?

**UPDATE 10/16/2019 1601HRS EST**

```
find /home/root/BACKUPS/backup.sql   | xargs zip -czvPf /home/root/BACKUPS/$(date +%F)_backup.sql.zip
find /home/root/BACKUPS/ -mtime +14 -type f -iname '*.backup.sql.zip' -exec rm {} \;
```

This did not remove the files that should have been removed. I'm not sure what I'm missing; maybe a ';' after the first line. Although the first line is running properly by zipping and naming the SQL file, the second line is not working.

Comment: Tag correctly. The command "mysqldump" suggest strongly that your question is not related to SQL Server.

Comment: done. thank you @SMor

Comment: Your find command doesn't work because it's trying to match a different filename than the files you're actually creating. Also, find has a `-delete` flag so you can skip the `-exec`. Do yourself a favour and read up on the meaning of the flags in find's man page.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. Finally found the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked perfectly for me.

**Backup.php**

```
#!/usr/bin/php

<?php
$file = "/home/root/BACKUPS/backup.sql";
$command = "mysqldump -uroot_admin -pkeypw --all-databases > $file";
system($command);
?>
```

**Backup.bat**

```
find /home/root/BACKUPS/backup.sql   | xargs zip -czvPf /home/root/BACKUPS/$(date +%F)_backup.sql.zip
find /home/root/BACKUPS -name "*.zip" -type f -mtime +15 -exec rm -f {} \;
```

**Reference:** https://tecadmin.net/delete-files-older-x-days/

Basically @Sebastian the `.backup.sql` part of the file name reference did not have to be included. So instead of `*.backup.sql.zip` it needed to simply be `*.zip` Thank you @Sebastian for the lead.

Comment: Since there will only be one `backup.sql` there's no need for using `find` and `xargs`. As well, using `-delete` flag to `find` is easier than `-exec rm -f {} \;`.

Answer (score 0):

cannot comment yet.

I guess you want something like this shell-command:

```
find /home/root/BACKUPS/ -mtime +15 -type f -iname '*.backup.sql.zip' -exec rm {} \;
```

Edit:

Some explanation: This finds and deletes (-exec rm {} \; )  all files (type f) with name ending in "backup.sql.zip" with a modification-time older than 15 days (mtime +15).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you @Sebastian. I added the line you provided to my *.bat file and got the following results...```updating: home/root/BACKUPS/backup.sql      (in=0) (out=0) (stored 0%)
Enter comment for home/root/BACKUPS/backup.sql:
enter new zip file comment (end with .):
total bytes=0, compressed=12 -> 0% savings``` and it did not remove the 1 file that should have been removed...which was created 09/30/2019 and well, another on 10/01/2019.

Comment: removed the ';' and it hit the line but it resulted in this feedback "find: missing argument to `-exec'"